# Why does a Tkinter label taking longer to render when I define a font?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

Here is some simplified code that highlight my problem:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        tic = time.perf_counter()

        for i in range(40):
            label = tk.Label(self, text = "testing this font", font = ("Courier", 18))
            label.pack()
            
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"{toc-tic:0.4f} seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    example.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I run this it takes about 2 seconds, however, if I remove "font=('Courier', 18)" from the tk.Label, then it takes about 0.03 seconds to load.  Is there a reason why not defining a font would allow the frame to render so much faster?

Thank you in advance,

-John

Comment: It depends on several factors. If you pick an 'easier' to render font like `Arial', it's faster. If you open a second window, it's faster as well. Never as fast as for the default settings, but that's probably because it's also the default for the underlying system involved in rendering the text. It's hard to say why exactly each option is a bit slower, but it's certainly a combination of many factors. (note that you see very different results on different OSes / window managers as well)

Comment: Have you tried using a `Font` object instead of a tuple to define the font?

Comment: @BryanOakley: Yeah, I tried a ```Font``` object but it took the same amount of render time as defining a Tuple.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. The code in this question comes up for me nearly instantly on my Mac and the output is `0.0160 seconds`. Maybe your system doesn't have a font by that exact name so it's having to do a little extra work to come up with a suitable substitute. If I use the font `(Bogus, 18)` it runs a little slower but still under 1/10th of a second.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to faulty behaviour of tk (version 8.6 and probably newer):

- Tk instantiates every widget with the default font.
- It then sets the font according to the `-font` parameter.
- if the default font isn't used by any other widget, it's unloaded.

The next widget will go through the same process. Since the default font got unloaded during the instanciation of the former widget, it will be loaded from disk again.

So, if the default font *isn't* used, it will be loaded from disk at *every* widget instanciation :)

If you create one widget without supplying the font parameter at the start of your programm, it will run fast.

Workarounds:

- keep a widget with the default font around
- set the overall default font to the desired font (and use it)
- first create widgets, then change all fonts at once